# Play wowza stream with authentication on media player

Tags: video, video-streaming, rtsp, wowza

I am trying to play a free live stream from live.russia.tv on vlc. I would have no issue keep playing it through chrome but the website stops responding after a while and the person who is watching is disabled so cannot refresh the page to let the video run again. Is there any way to play the stream through another media player such as VLC?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using rtsp protocol to stream video. In that case you can test your video on ffplay. It is a testing player for ffmpeg. But you need to have ffmpeg installed to work with ffplay. After installed you can play the video by entering following command.

```
ffplay [video url]
```

You can find more information about ffplay on [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html) link.